# Change URL of Education in Developer Story

Tags: support, developer-story

I entered a URL to the entry of the bachelor's programme I added to my developer story.

My University changed its web presence and now it is invalid. But I cannot edit it because the text box is disabled.

How can I edit the URL of an education entry in the developer story?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your [Developer Story page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/7917910), scroll down to the **Education** section.

In the section, you can see the gear/settings icon in the right top corner of the box, clicking on that it will open two options. By using **Edit** option, you can change the URL of your Education entry.

> [image: Education - Edit]

Comment: I did try that but the URL field is disabled on this form